# Using single sas token for every pipeline agent to upload on blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cloud-services

The problem is I don't want to create a new SAS token for every agent. I want to use the same sas token for a specific period on every agent of the pipeline

I already tried to create an SAS token without mentioning any IP and it failed to upload the file on blob storage.

The reason to have a universal sas key is that I don't want to use an access key or connection string to create an SAS token again and again

Comment: I haven't tried yet.My PC isn't set up yet because I moved, but I could try this and will update you on it.

Comment: Will wait for your update.

Comment: Yes working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use same sas token for a specific period on every agent of pipeline

Based on your requirement, you can use a separate Pipeline to create SAS token. Then you can use the [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to save the SAS Token.

In this case, every pipeline can use the same SAS via using Variable Group in the Pipeline.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a variable group in **Pipelines -> Library** and add a variable with empty value.

For example:

[image]

Step2: Use the following bash script to update the variable value in Variable Group. Use the Rest API: [Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedTask/Variablegroups/Update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
#getting date and time in format
expiry_time=$(date -u -d '+30 minutes' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ)

#creating a sas token
sas_token=$(az storage container generate-sas --account-name <blobname> --name <containername> --permissions dlwr  --account-key $(key)  --expiry $expiry_time  --output tsv )

curl -X PUT \
-u  :$(pat) https://dev.azure.com/{Organizationname}/{Projectname}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroupId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1 \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{ 
  
  "variables": {
    "SASToken": {
      "isSecret":true,
      "value": "$sas_token"
    }

  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "{VariableGroupName}",
  "description": "Updated variable group"
}'
```

Step3: In other Pipelines, you can directly use the Variable in the Variable Group to upload the files.

For example:

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group
```

At the same time, you can set  [scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the Pipeline to regularly update the SASToken value in the variable group.